# Specify Multi-Level columns using pd.read_clipboard?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's some data from another question:

```
main    Meas1     Meas2 Meas3   Meas4  Meas5
sublvl  Value     Value Value   Value   Value       
count   7.000000  1.0   1.0     582.00  97.000000       
mean    30        37.0  26.0    33.03   16.635350
```

I would like to read in this data in such a way that the first column is actually the index, and the first two rows are treated as multi-level columns where `MeasX` is the first level, and `Value` is the second level.

How can I do this using `pd.read_clipboard`?

---

My `pd.read_clipboard` series:

- [How do you handle column names having spaces in them when using pd.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528198/)
- [How to handle custom named index when copying a dataframe using pd.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725500/how-to-handle-custom-named-index-when-copying-a-dataframe-using-pd-read-clipboar)
- [Copying MultiIndex dataframes with pd.read_clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740537/copying-multiindex-dataframes-with-pd-read-clipboard)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [17]: pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+', index_col=[0], header=[0,1])
Out[17]: 
main   Meas1 Meas2 Meas3   Meas4     Meas5
sublvl Value Value Value   Value     Value
count    7.0   1.0   1.0  582.00  97.00000
mean    30.0  37.0  26.0   33.03  16.63535
```

Comment: What really amazes me about this answer is how close I came to it: `pd.read_clipboard(index=[0], header=[1, 2])`

Comment: Probably because of all the other dumb mistakes, such as `index` instead of `index_col`, and not specifying sep... etc etc. I have a lot to learn.